# same code gives different results on two Nvidia 2080Ti GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have two same 2080Ti installed on one desktop for general computing purposes and my code is written using cublas library. The machine is only a couple of weeks old. Everything looks fine until three days ago, when I got error running the code on one of the card. Then I switch to another card by using cudaSetDevice(), and run the same code. No error happens.

What could be the reasons for that problem? Did I break one card?